# Divide Screen evenly android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, screen, screen-orientation

In the task to divide screen evenly I used **Weight** attribute many times.

But is there any better way to divide screen in equal modules ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do so is to use the TableLayout. You can add as many TableRows as you need, so it saves you the trouble of adding various child horizontal LinearLayouts inside parent vertical LinearLayout.

However you will still have to use the weight attribute if you want a specific division inside that row.